# Nginx appending 443 to rewritten routes

Tags: http, nginx, laravel

I am trying to redirect all http traffic to https. Below is my config. The traffic redirects but it adds 443 to the route which causes my app to fail.

```
http://mysite.com/login
```

Becomes

```
https://mysite.com:443/login
```

Here is my nginx config file:

```
server {
  listen         80;
  server_name    mysite.com www.mysite.com;
  rewrite        ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
}

server {

listen  443;

ssl    on;
ssl_certificate    /etc/ssl/mysite.com.crt;
ssl_certificate_key    /etc/ssl/server.key;


server_name     mysite.com www.mysite.com;

root            /var/www/html/mysite/public/;

client_max_body_size 150M;

location /
{
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
}

# Enforce No WWW - I put this in an include:
# include /etc/nginx/includes/enforce_non_www;
if ($host ~* ^www\.(.*))
{
    set $host_without_www $1;
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ $scheme://$host_without_www/$1 permanent;
}

# Check if file exists
if (!-e $request_filename)
{
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 last;
    break;
}

# catch all
error_page 404 /index.php;

# The PHP Inclusion Block
# include /etc/nginx/includes/php;
location ~ \..*/.*\.php$
{
    # I'm pretty sure this stops people trying to traverse your site to get to other PHP files
    return 403;
}
location ~ \.php(.*)$
{
    # Pass the PHP files to PHP FastCGI for processing
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}

# Deny Any Access to .htaccess Files That May Be Present (not usually in issue in Laravel)
# include /etc/nginx/includes/deny_htaccess;
location ~ /\.ht
{
    deny all;
}

}
```

Comment: Does it happen when you leave the 'without_www' stuff out?

Comment: I just tried removing it.. Same problem.

Comment: 443 is HTTPS port. If it interferes with your application it probably means that your application doesn't work with HTTPS.

`https://mysite.com:443/login` is absolutely the same as `https://mysite.com/login`